# my greenplum insert slow

Tags: greenplum

Bulk data insertion from greenplum from Oracle through JDBC, plain text data, storage speed is very slow, 200 per second. Is there any good solution?

I try to insert data from Oracle to HDFS, the same configuration, 20,000 data per second.

Comment: Try using more parallel threads. 10-20, if your infrastructure can handle it.

Comment: What JDBC tool are you using to insert data from Oracle to Greenplum?  If you are just looping through a ResultSet and doing a single insert, yeah, that will be really slow.

Comment: That sounds like you do single inserts, that will be very slow. Try one or more of the following: prepared statements (and re-use the prepared statement), group inserts into a single transaction, copy, external table.